# YII PHP Fatal error: Class 'CWebApplication' not found

Tags: php, yii

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'CWebApplication' not found in /DOMAIN/framework/YiiBase.php on line 125
```

I could access the same on my localhost but cannot access in my server.
Please throw some light.

**framework/YiiBase.php**

```
123 public static function createApplication($class,$config=null)
124 {
125  return new $class($config);
126 }
```

**protected/index.php**

```
<?php

// change the following paths if necessary
$yii=dirname(__FILE__).'/../framework/yii.php';
$config=dirname(__FILE__).'/protected/config/main.php';

// remove the following lines when in production mode
defined('YII_DEBUG') or define('YII_DEBUG',true);
// specify how many levels of call stack should be shown in each log message
defined('YII_TRACE_LEVEL') or define('YII_TRACE_LEVEL',3);

require_once($yii);
Yii::createWebApplication($config)->run();
?>
```

Comment: Always add the relevant part of the code.. What's in line 125 in `YiiBase.php`?

Comment: Its understood that since i have not made changes in the framework , it would be the same as default.

Comment: Though i have added. Please dont down vote :(

Comment: What do you mean by "I could access the same on my localhost but cannot access in my server". Are you trying to run this from the command line?

Comment: No! I meant when i run the index.php on localhost it shows me the content but over server i encountered this error. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

need write

```
Yii::createApplication('YourWebApplication', $config)->run(); // or standard CWebApplication
```

Comment: It still does not work. Please tell me if i could add more details?